# Join tables and append columns

Tags: mysql

I need to join two tables, and append columns where certain data matches. The two tables are setup like so:

```
Apple         | Flavor
Fuji          | 1
Red Delicious | 2

Flavor | Quality  
1      | Sour  
1      | Sweet
2      | Bitter
2      | Sweet
```

And I need to append a column for each matching flavor quality like so:

```
Apple         | Quality 1 | Quality 2 
Fuji          | sour      | sweet
Red Delicious | bitter    | sweet
```

Notice I also need append an auto-integer to each column header appended.

This seems like a tall task and I'm not sure where to start? Is this even possible? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: we are not gonna write the code for you, at least show some effort en try something

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible with SQL. Not in any sane fashion anyway. Just run one query to fetch the apples, and a second to fetch its qualities.

Comment: @GertB. Generally I'd agree with your sentiment, but I don't think there's much he could write here.

Comment: Is the Flavor kinds known(how much they are)?

Comment: How do you determine which flavour is Quality 1?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your responses. The main point of this question was to determine if such a task is conceivably possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can group related rows together and concatenate the Quality values for the respective group. This produces *one* column, a string with comma-separated values.  See [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

```
SELECT a.Apple, GROUP_CONCAT(f.Quality) AS Qualities
FROM apples a JOIN flavors f ON a.flavor = f.flavor
GROUP BY a.Apple;
```

This doesn't do exactly what you asked, because it doesn't separate the Quality values in to separate columns. But it's a pretty simple query, and you can [explode()](http://php.net/explode) the string of qualities after you fetch it back into your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a variable number of columns like that. Use one query to fetch the apples, then loop over the result set to fetch their qualities. You can merge the result sets together using your server-side scripting language if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Against what Mark said, you can have a variable number of columns. Though I'm demonstrating here just how nonsense it actually is.

Usually you would have a single statement like

```
SELECT * FROM apples a JOIN flavors f ON a.flavor = f.flavor;
```

then you'd do little voodoo on application level and that's it. Here's how this simple query would look like to get a static number of columns:

```
select
Apple,
max(case when my_quality_numbering = 1 then Quality else null end) as Quality1,
max(case when my_quality_numbering = 2 then Quality else null end) as Quality2
from (
select
a.Apple,
f.Quality,
case when (if(@prev_apple != a.Apple, @quality_no := 1, @quality_no := @quality_no + 1)) is null then null
     when (@prev_apple := a.Apple) is null then null
else @quality_no end as my_quality_numbering           
from
apples a 
join flavors f on a.Flavor = f.Flavor
, (select @quality_no := 0, @prev_apple := NULL) v
order by a.Apple
) sq
group by Apple
```

- see it working live in an **<kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/642b6/5/0)</kbd>**

And this is only half the work. To have variable number of columns, you'd have to write a stored procedure, that reads from the inner query, how much columns are needed. Then you'd have to build your query string for the outer query and execute all that via a prepared statement. Pretty much work for a simple query. Again, I did above query just for fun, but in general it's really not worth the trouble.